# What transactions does commit / rollback affect?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does it only affect whatever commands were after the relevant BEGIN transaction?

For example:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE orders SET orderdate = '01-08-2013' WHERE orderno > '999'
```

Now, assume someone else performs a data import that inserts 10,000 new records into another table.

If I subsequently issue a ROLLBACK command, do those records get discarded or is it just the command above that gets rolled back?

Sorry if this a stupid question, I'm only just starting to use COMMIT and ROLLBACK.

Comment: Wikipedia page on [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID): "ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) is a set of properties that guarantee that database transactions are processed reliably." and note the `I`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any transaction is confined to the connection it was opened on.

One of the four ACID properties of any relational database management system is Isolation. That means your actions are isolated from other connections and vice versa until you commit. Any change you do is invisible to other connections and if you roll it back they will never know it happened. That means in turn that changes that happened somewhere else are invisible to you until they are committed. Particularly that means that you can't ROLLBACK anyone else's changes.

The Isolation is achieved in one of two ways. One way is to "lock" the resource (e.g. the row). If that happens any other connection trying to read from that row has to wait until you finish your transaction. 
The other way is to create a copy of the row that contains the old values. In this case all other connections will see the old version until you commit your transaction.

SQL Server can use both isolation methods. Which one is used depends on the isolation level you choose. The two Snapshot Isolation Levels provide the "copy method" the other four use the "lock method". The default isolation level of "read committed" is one of the "lock method" isolation levels.

Be aware however that the isolation level "READ UNCOMMITTED" basically circumvents these mechanisms and allows you to read changes that others started and have not yet committed. This is a special isolation level that can be helpful when diagnosing a problem but should be avoided in production code.